# Simpler way to add the XDEBUG_SESSION_START cookie/variable?

Tags: php, vim, xdebug

I use `vim` with `debugger` and `xdebug` to walk trough PHP applications.

In firefox (or any other browser), I then need to open up the page, call a URL with `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1` appended to it, in order to tell the `xdebug` PHP-plugin to start the debug-server.

This works fine, but can it be made simpler?

Is there some plugin for firefox that allows me add this session automatically? Some `xdebug` setting that allows me to circumvent this alltogether? Or some vim-addon, script or trick that allows me to call firefox with that parameter added automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look to the [firefox extensions page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/xdebug).

Some time ago I used [vimxdebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimxdebug/?src=search). It did the job fine, but it's no supported in firefox 8.0. There's also other extension, [easy Xdebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/?src=search), but I didn't try it.

Comment: Thanks. I never considered Easy Xdebug, because it says it is meant for Netbeans. Reading on now, shows me, that assumption was wrong. A comment on the pluginpage lead me to http://highervisibilitywebsites.com/simple-cross-browser-xdebug-helper-session-starter-and-stopper-no-add-ons-needed which is nicer IMHO.

Comment: I'm using Easy XDebug with JIdea and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

there is a list of extensions to use for different browsers at http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser-extensions

It doesn't matter for which IDE they are, as they should work for all.

cheers,
Derick